# JQuery: Parse XML document to find a tag with special character ':'

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, xml-parsing

I have to parse an xml document which has certain tags as follows:

```
        <result>
            <ns0:Item>
                <ItemID>1365</ItemID>
                <ItemNumber>671150</ItemNumber>
            </ns0:Item>
            <ns0:Item>
                <ItemID>1305</ItemID>
                <ItemNumber>6700150</ItemNumber>
            </ns0:Item>
        </result>
```

> > 1. If I want to 'find' if the document contains the tag **'ns0:Item'**, the below code is not able to do so.
> > 2. If I remove the colon ':' character then it is able to parse the xml successfully.

Code:

```
$(document).find('ns0:Item').each(function(){
    ....<br/>
    ....<br/>
    ....<br/>
});
```

Please help how to parse ':' character in the xml.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The colon separates the namespace-prefix from the element name. The value of the prefix is not semantically important; what is important is the namespace string. In your case `ns0` refers to a string not shown in your code; it is likely specified somewhere near the top of your XML document.

To select an item with a given prefix, and assuming you are doing the selection in a `success` callback of an ajax call, I think you want something like this:

```
success: function(xml) {
    var ns = "uri:whatever";  // the actual namespace, not the prefix
    $(xml).find('Item').each(function(){
        if ($(this).get(0).namespaceURI == ns) {
           ....
        }
    });
}
```

You used `document` as the variable name in your code, representing an XML document. That seems confusing.  I'd recommend against using the name `document` to refer to anything besides the browser's HTML document.

Comment: The namespace definition is present at the top of the xml. Thanks Chheso, I was able to search for the 'Item' tag without mentioning the namespace prefix 'ns0'.

Comment: Thanks too for the brief help on naming conventions. I have incorporated that too!